# Регулярное выражения для поиска мобильного телефона в теле письма, но чтобы в подписях сообщений не детектировался

Tags: регулярные-выражения, email, поиск, передача-данных

При деловом общении по электронной почте у каждого сотрудника настроена подпись сообщения, которое начинается, как правило со слов "с уважением" и содержит такие данные, как - Фамилия и Имя, должность, телефон/факт, компания, электронная почта и тд.

Необходимо детектировать при ведении переписки номера телефонов в теле письма, но чтобы в подписях он не детектировался (система dlp не реагировала на него). Для этого необходимо составить регулярное выражение. Я захожу со стороны проверки, что стоит перед ..
Вот пример моего регулярного выражения, но нуэны доработки - `(?<!(тел|моб|телефон|т|.\s|(:\s)|(.:\s)))(?:\+7|7|8)[\d\-\(\) ]{9,}\d`